# Pandas merge single column dataframe with another dataframe of multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have one dataframe_1 as

```
        date
0 2020-01-01
1 2020-01-02
2 2020-01-03
3 2020-01-04
4 2020-01-05
```

and another dataframe_2 as

```
             date source dest     price
634647 2020-09-18    EUR  USD  1.186317
634648 2020-09-19    EUR  USD  1.183970
634649 2020-09-20    EUR  USD  1.183970
```

I want to merge them on `'date'` but the problem is dataframe_1 last date is '2021-02-15' and dataframe_2 last date is '2021-02-01'.

I want the resulting dataframe as

```
             date source dest     price
634647 2021-02-01    EUR  USD  1.186317
634648 2021-02-02    NaN  NaN  NaN
634649 2021-02-03    Nan  NaN  NaN
...
             date source dest     price
634647 2021-02-13    NaN  NaN  NaN
634648 2021-02-14    NaN  NaN  NaN
634649 2021-02-25    NaN  NaN  NaN
```

But I am not able to do it using pd.merge, please ignore the indices in the dataframes.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your question / instructions are not very clear, unfortunately, at least for me.

Comment: you need to look at and understand the **how** parameter.  Looks like you need **left** or **outer** but you have not really stated your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use join to do it.

```
df1.set_index('date').join(df2.set_index('date'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sos, I was able to solve it using reset_index instead of set index, but your answer got me thinking, once again thanks a lot.